# Magento - Adding quantity box to upsell / related products

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I have a question regarding Magento. I want to be able to add a quantity box to the products that show up in the 'related products' list that is shown on the product detail page. This way a visitor can order a related item multple times instead of only once per action. I have been looking for a solution for this for over 2 weeks, but I can't seem to find anything usefull. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to edit this template: `your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml`. If you do not have that file already in your theme, simply copy it in your theme and package following the rest of the path. 
There you can add you Qty input box and add Add to Cart button and change the URL to include the qty. You should bear in mind that you may have also configurable/bundle products displayed as an up-sell, so you should cover these too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, can you be more specific about what code I need to edit / input to make this input field work for the related products? Thanks in advance!